# jquery - check to see if ANY file is selected without using ID

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a reusable external js file to validate multiple pages. My current code for what I am asking is:

```
if($('#file1').val().length == 0 && 
    $('#file2').val().length == 0) { 
    alert("ERROR! Select at least one file before submitting form!") 
    $('#file1').focus(); 
    validForm = false; 
}
```

This code is replicated on other pages, but there can be `n` number of files, I would like to either iterate through the DOM and check to see if a file is selected in at least one. If it is not, then return false.

I don't want to define what each ID is, but rather find each one through the dom and check it that way or if there is an easier way to do that.

Pseudo Code

```
var fileCount = 0;

interate through dom {
  if($('#fileN').val().length > 0 { 
    fileCount++;
  }
}

if (fileCount == 0){
   alert("ERROR! Select at least one file before submitting form!") 
    $('#file1').focus(); 
    validForm = false; 
}
```

Comment: Just at the offset - do you want to error check ONLY if BOTH file1 & file2 doesn't exist or if just one of them doesn't exist?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a class for this?

Comment: The form is not valid if one of them is not selected.  If 1 & 2 is empty, the form is not valid. Otherwise if one is selected it is valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.filter` on similar ID's:

```
var atleastOneFileSelected = $("[id^=file]").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val().length > 0;
}).length > 0;
```

Comment: This is great! This is exactly what I was looking for! I knew it was simpler than how I was making it